# What is the best way to handle Booleans?

Tags: swift

My app is available in German, There are around 30 Xcode generated Localizable.strings files (means app is available in 30 more languages) i'm slowly converting to swift `structs`, personal opinion.

```
struct German {
    let contacting_app_services: String = "Kontaktiere App Service.."
    let validating_user: String = "Validiere Nutzer"
    let email_in_use: String = "Diese e-mail wird bereits von einem andern Konto genutzt"
    let account_not_found: String = "Nutzerkonto nicht gefunden. Bitte prüfen und nochmals versuchen"
    let valid_email: String = "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige e-mail Adresse ein"
}
```

Now, I check if the device is in German:

```
extension Locale {
    func isGerman() -> Bool {
        return Locale.preferredLanguages[0].range(of:"de") != nil
    }
}
```

And update my UI with:

```
if Locale.current.isGerman() {
    self.errorLabel.text = German().valid_email
}
```

What i'm trying to do:

- Get rid of the `if statement` and use a cleaner way.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WweunQVz ? " I don't use localizations" use them?

Comment: @Larme please make this an answer so i can upvote + accept

Comment: `I don't use xcode localization (probably because there are about 30 language files)` wat?

Comment: There are around 30 Xcode generated  `Localizable.strings` files (means app is available in 30 more languages) i'm slowly converting to swift structs, personal opinion.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) and its string templates.

Comment: @CaplinYT But that's kind of the point. All strings of a language are separated out, and can be modified/owned by separate people/teams/whatever. If for some reason you feel like this is inadequate for you (almost certainly isn't) and you feel compelled to use structs, at least put them behind a protocol, and use polymorphism to pick the right localized string for a given call site.

Comment: What exactly was the plan here? You're going to `if/else-if/else` through every supported langauge, at every call site where you want a localized string?

Comment: No, just for German. It's the last language I'll use, plus, i wanted to learn something new, and i did. thank you again, @Larme

Comment: What about the other 29 languages?

Comment: A problem for the future.

Comment: It's a really predictable problem though, and you should prepare for it. I *strongly* recommend you start using polymorphism to pick the strings, because you will end up with the "if/else-if/else through every supported langauge, at every call site where you want a localized string" situation, which would be an absolute nightmare.

Comment: This is a personal app i'm working on, it's small, when i'm bored i write everything from scratch, so it's just part of my learning strategy on Swift. Using new methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199744/discussion-between-alexander-and-caplin-yt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. Even if you have some inexplicable repulsion to the localization tools already built into the system, don't do this.

Just imagine what I night mare you would run into if you had to support multiple languages. Imagine you wanted to add support for the 6 official languages of the UN.

```
if Locale.current.isArabic {
    self.errorLabel.text = Arabic().valid_email
}
else if Locale.current.isChinese {
    self.errorLabel.text =  Chinese().valid_email
}
else if Locale.current.isEnglish {
    self.errorLabel.text =  English().valid_email
}
else if Locale.current.isFrench {
    self.errorLabel.text = French().valid_email
}
else if Locale.current.isGerman {
    self.errorLabel.text = German().valid_email
}
else if Locale.current.isRussian {
    self.errorLabel.text = Russian().valid_email
}
else if Locale.current.isSpanish {
    self.errorLabel.text = Spanish().valid_email
} else {
    // What would you even put here?
}
```

What an absolute disaster. There are so many issues with it:

1. You would end up repeating this `if`/`else if`/`else` ladder *at every place where you want a localized string!*
2. What do you put in the `else` case? A default language?
3. What if you ever change your mind about what to do in the `else` case? Are you  going to go back and change it every where?
4. What if you want to add a new language? Are you going to go back and add it in everywhere? What if you forget a call site?
5. How will this look when you want to support 30 languages?

That's obviously a complete non-starter.

Instead, use polymorphism to pick the right string for you:

```
protocol LocalizedStrings {
    var contactingAppServices: String { get }
    var validatingUser: String { get }
    var emailInUse: String { get }
    var accountNotFound: String { get }
    var validEmail: String { get }
}

struct EnglishLocalizedStrings: LocalizedStrings {
    let contactingAppServices = "Contacting App Services, please wait."
    let validatingUser = "Validating user, please wait."
    let emailInUse = "This e-mail is already in use."
    let accountNotFound = "Account not found."
    let invalidEmail = "This e-mail is not valid"
}

struct ArabicLocalizedStrings: LocalizedStrings {
    // ...
}

// Somewhere in the initalization of your app 
let localizedStrings: LocalizedString = PickTheRightLocalizationStringsObjectForTheUser() 

// somewhere where you need localized strings: 
self.errorLabel.text = localizedStrings.validEmail
```

And then you can just rely on the dynamic dispatch mechanism to do the branching for you to pick the right string for the job, rather than manually enumerating each possible case yourself, everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
protocol Translations {
    var valid_email: String { get }
}

struct German: Translations {
    var valid_email: String = "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige e-mail Adresse ein"
}

struct English: Translations {
    var valid_email: String = ""
}

extension Locale {
    static func isGerman() -> Bool {
        return Locale.preferredLanguages[0].range(of:"de") != nil
    }

    static func language() -> Translations {
        if isGerman() {
            return German()
        }
        return English()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let errorLabel = UILabel()
errorLabel.text = Locale.language().valid_email
```

Comment: Won't this produce an empty string for English, while for German it will produce a valid one?